# xorg.conf for VGA connection with Sony Bravia at Lucid Lynx

Tags: xorg

Here is my current `xorg.conf` file contents:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "CRT-0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce4 MX 4000"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
EndSection
```

Indeed, there is a GeForce4 MX 4000 from nVidia installed, and the nVidia configuration software works fine.

Here is the full case: I was using another monitor, and everything was fine. Then, I switched from it to the Sony Bravia TV (model KDL-32EX405). The previous xorg.conf simply gave me a black screen, so I backed it up and I had to make this minimal xorg.conf file, so I was able to use it on its current `640 x 480` resolution I am now. It is kind of funny: a very big screen with a very small resolution...

Anyway, I am no X Server expert, so I need to know what to type into xorg.conf so I can use a better resolution. Remember: no HDMI available, only VGA cable. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a configuration in [a message from an email list](http://old.nabble.com/xorg.conf-help-needed!-td20519164s24859.html), and it worked for me. Now I am enjoying a `1320 x 768` resolution, which is paradise comparing to the `640 x 480` I was stuck before.

I just had to add a few lines to the Monitor and Screen sections. Here is their new versions:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "CRT-0"
    Option          "IgnoreEDID" 
    VertRefresh     30-90 
    HorizSync       20-150 
    Modeline        "HDTV-1360x768" 85.500 1360 1424 1536 1792 768 771 777 795 +Hsync +Vsync
    DisplaySize     320 180
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth 24 
    SubSection "Display" 
        ViewPort 0 0 
        Depth       24 
        Modes "HDTV-1360x768"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```